# Transplanting Geth Data

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging, geth-clique

I am wondering if it is possible to transplant a geth node from one computer by overwriting the `.Ethereum` folder with a full synced node's `.Ethereum` folder.

Comment: It is quite possible, an excerpt from the Geth Wiki: 

The Go-Ethereum Client offers the 

    geth export <filename>

and

    geth import <filename>

commands.

Always secure your private-keys in advance when you change client options.

  [1]: https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/install-and-build/backup-restore

Comment: @toothleth_byte Thank you! This is just what I needed!